# Installing dependencys with Gradle Kotlin DSL does not work

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, jetpack-compose-navigation

Hi everyone I am new to IntelliJ in general and especially to Gradle and I feel like a total noob. :D

Im not sure if this is a Kotlin DSL thing or if I just do it the wrong way and it wouldn't work in Groovey either.

After hours of trial and error and reading other SO posts I'm still not able to install a simple dependency... it can't be that hard...

Currently I am playing around with Jetpack Compose for Desktop even though it's still in alpha and it works but for the love of god I am not able to add a dependency.

So here is my Problem:

I try to install the dependency like they say I should in
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#kts

and yes I know it's an android package so it may not compile or it may crash during runtime but shouldn't it at least find and download the dependency???

So... if I add

```
implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.0-alpha10")
```

to my build.gradle.kts
[image]

And try to compile it I get an exception during the build process:

[image]

What I tried so far:

I checked if the repository maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev")
who is configured in my build.gradle.kts repositories-section and in my settings.gradle.kts pluginManagement-section contains the package that I want.
The site https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.navigation/navigation-compose?repo=space-public-compose-dev tells me, that the repository contains the package that I need.

I checked the error log itself.
But I don't relly know what it tries to say.
I use Java SDK16, since I expect downward compatibility and the fact that the dependency is still in alpha I assume it should be compatible.
I use Kotlin 1.5....
that's it.

Thanks for reading all that :) I really appreciate your time... If I forgot some crucial information let me know and I will add it as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

the problem which I feel is, is you are basically opening the wrong file. (I don't use jetpack compose so the answer might differ)

on the top left corner in the image, where there is `project` dropdown, open it and select `android`.

now there will be a different set of files in the Gradle folder, in fact, there will be 2 different files in that folder.

1. `build.gradle (project: <project_name>)`
2. `build.gradle (Module: <project_name>.app)`

open the second file and there will be dependencies copy + paste implementation code there.

the file which you have opened is actually the first file.

Comment: If this would be an Android Project you'd be right but the thing is this is Jetpack Compose for Desktop and therefor this is not an Android Project. I can't select 'Android'. It seems like only Android Projects have the secon build.gradle file since every other Kotlin Project only has one build.gradle file

Answer (score 0):

Well... here I am back again answering my own question.
After I switched to the terminal in IntelliJ Idea (which to be honest I could have thought of that prior to posting my question) there was highlighted text that gave me the necessary insight, why it wasn't working.
[image]

And after some searching the web in order to find out what an "aar" file is and why I didn't get a jar file like I expected it turns out that android has it's own little file format for android applications and that those cannot be used in regular java/kotlin projects.

I read somewhere, that 'aar' files contain a jar file and some other stuff and extracting the jar file from the aar file may be a way to get it working, but it didn't fix anything, maybe because the dependencies of the navigation package are aar files as well and therefor I'd need those packages as well and extract the jar file from those as well and it all seems like this isn't the right way...

So I guess I have to wait until Jetpack Compose for desktop somehow is able to use aar files or until the repositories deliver the packages in a regular jar file.